# How to insert data in foreign key column in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table that has an external key value. So I can save photos of a letter on the photo table. This table has three columns:

```
{
    Id is not null,
    Picture is not null,
    Latterid (Foreign key) is not null
}
```

I do not know what grammar should I write to add a bit to this table

My program is written in C# and I used Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Check this guide out, it gives some guidance on how to add a field to both the database and the model using EF.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/new-field